# How can I switch into golang.google.cn when I use go get to fetch some package?

Tags: go

golang.org is blocked in China, but golang.google.cn is accessible. How can I switch into golang.google.cn when I use go get  to fetch some package?

Comment: go is hot in China,but  it often block by the Great Wall ......

Comment: Check if the package exists in golang.google.cn , if it does not you may need a proxy to change your Ip address

Comment: edit /etc/hosts  perhaps?

Comment: just cross the great wall.

Answer (score 1):

There are few options, one is to change git configuration:

```
git config --global url."https://golang.google.cn".insteadOf "https://golang.org"
```